# Return int from Query

Tags: sql, dapper

I have the following procedure which doesnt seem to work at all and I am struggling to understand how I can return a single variable;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ManufacturingStages_ReturnNextOrder]
    @StageType nvarchar(50),
    @StageRelatedPart int
AS
    Declare @SomeVal int

    SELECT stageType, stageRelatedPart, @SomeVal = Max(stageOrder)
    FROM ProductManufacturingStages
    GROUP BY stageType, stageRelatedPart
    HAVING stageType = @StageType AND stageRelatedPart = @StageRelatedPart

    RETURN @SomeVal
```

I plan to call this procedure using Dapper in order to obtain the last known stageOrder from the table;

```
DynamicParameters parameters = new DynamicParameters();
parameters.Add("@StageType", "Manufacturing");
parameters.Add("@StageRelatedPart", 8137);
int i = Globals.db.QuerySingle<int>("ManufacturingStages_ReturnNextOrder", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

How do I need to structure the procedure in order to return the value of stageOrder? Usually I would create a Model and return it that way but I feel that maybe slightly overkill.

Comment: I believe `QuerySingle` is expecting a result set with a single column of type `T` - did you try using SELECT @someVal instead?

Comment: if you trying to get the single value, you could try to use SELECT TOP 1 ... and ORDER By

Answer (score 1):

What you really need is a function but you can use the output parameter for stored procs too.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ManufacturingStages_ReturnNextOrder]
@StageType nvarchar(50),
@StageRelatedPart int, @SomeVal int OUTPUT
AS

SELECT stageType, stageRelatedPart, @SomeVal = Max(stageOrder)
FROM ProductManufacturingStages
GROUP BY stageType, stageRelatedPart
HAVING stageType = @StageType AND stageRelatedPart = @StageRelatedPart
```

The parameters collection of your command object should include the output parameter(using the direction property) which should contain a value after the call.